# "Java(TM) Platform SE binary has stopped working" error with Tomcat server

Tags: java, tomcat, windows-8

The following error message appears while running Tomcat web server:

> "Java(TM) Platform SE binary has stopped working A problem caused the
>   program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and
>   notify you if a solution is available."

Faulting application path: C:...\jdk1.6.0_38\bin\java.exe

Faulting module path: C:..\jdk1.6.0_38\jre\bin\dt_socket.dll

OS: **Windows 8** (64 bit).

Java: **1.6.0_38** (64 bit).

Tomcat: **7.0.25**.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug with Java 1.6.

See: http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6810745

Even the latest 1.6.0.45 has the same one.

I have been able to replace the JDK/JRE with 1.7.0.80 in which the issue appears to have been resolved. I wasn't able to upgrade to 1.8 as the specific application had issues with it.

Keep in mind that both 1.6 and 1.7 are no longer supported. As of this writing the latest one is 1.8.

Just make sure to download the appropriate 32 or 64 version. You can find the previous versions here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/archive-139210.html